# Can anybody see what is wrong with this Roblox script?

Tags: lua, roblox

Can anybody see what is wrong with this Roblox script?

```
local a1 = game.CoreGui.DBXBRGUI.Menu
local a2 = game.CoreGui.DBXBRGUI.Opener
if a1.Visible == true then do
     a2.Visible = false
elseif a2.Visible == true then do
     a1.Visible = false
end
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Is there an error? If so, please post it. Is it not doing what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't put "do" after "then" (that's your problem)

Second, just use else not elseif because something may be different.

This is what it should look like:

```
local a1 = game.CoreGui.DBXBRGUI.Menu
local a2 = game.CoreGui.DBXBRGUI.Opener
if a1.Visible == true then
     a2.Visible = false else
     a1.Visible = false
end
```

I'm using common sense to say that this is probably what you want:

```
local a1 = game.CoreGui.DBXBRGUI.Menu
local a2 = game.CoreGui.DBXBRGUI.Opener
if a1.Visible == true then
     a1.Visible = true
     a2.Visible = false else
     a1.Visible = false
     a2.Visible = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you are trying to reference CoreGui which is strictly for Roblox's default GUIs. Any custom GUIs you make will be in each Player's PlayerGui. That is referenced by doing game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.
It is worth noting that for anything clientside (such as GUIs), you should check if the objects exist before trying to use them. This is done via the parent:FindFirstChild(name) or parent:WaitForChild(name) functions.

Secondly, you are using a "do-end"-block inside your conditional statement. A "do-end" block requires an end. You also do not need that block, so I suggest removing it. If we add the end to the correct location in your code, we get this:

```lua
if CONDITION then 
  do
    -- stuff

  end -- you're missing this end
elseif CONDITION2 then
  do

  end -- you're also missing this end
end
```

Because of the missing ends, your code is interpreted as follows:

```lua
if CONDITION then 
  do
  elseif CONDITION2 then
  do
end
```

As you see, the "elseif" appears inside the do-block inside the first if, instead of as an elseif to the first if. You cannot have an "elseif"-statement without an if, so that's what errors.

Your code would ideally look like this:

```lua
local Gui = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("DBXRGUI")
local a1 = Gui.Opener
local a2 = Gui.Menu
if a1 == true then
   a1.Visible = false
elseif a2.Visible == true then
   a2.Visible = false
end
```